# routing traffic from http to https through nginx load balancer

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a loadbalance, i want to setup the ngix to route all http traffix to backend services runing on https?

I am not sure whether it is possible? any advice is highly appriciated

Comment: but this isn't done quite often. Mostly, https routing happens in nginx layer not at upstream end. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used nginx as loadbalancer, but as a reverse proxy only. But the idea should be similar since the task is to redirect all http traffic to https.

```
server {

    listen         80;
    server_name    ...
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    ...
}

server {
    listen         443;
    server_name    ...
    ssl on;
    ...
}
```

Note the line `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` - it will redirect all http traffic to https.

Comment: but this isn't done quite often. Mostly, https routing happens in nginx layer not at upstream end. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @harshavmb, Yes, https routing happens in the nginx layer. This is exactly what I am doing here.

Comment: aww..!! but should backend worry about `https/http` as nginx is doing the job? AFAIK, they shouldn't be impacted at all.

Comment: @harshavmb, Backend doesn't care about https/http in this case. All this stuff is done on the reverse proxy side. This is the point of a reverse proxy server.

Comment: sorry for abit confusing, my setup is abit different as I want to have a loadbalancer run on http and my backend services run on https (spring application using jks). The reason as Nginx does not support jks format keystore. This setup is just a workaround solution for testing purpose only while waiting infra team to setup F5; I am working in the bank so proccess is pretty so low. @Nurzhan

Comment: @Van, You can try to convert `jks` to `.p12` format and use in nginx. AFAIK, all the SSL configuring is usually done in nginx and not backend.

Comment: @Nurzhan, a mentioned this is just a setup for quick test while waiting for our infra team setting up F5 loadbalancer. my concern is that is it possible to have Loader balancer and back-end services having different certificate  format, that is what I am not sure..

Comment: @Van, I might be wrong but if load balander is configured using SSL, then the backend is using plain http. Backend uses http since they are not publicly accessible and stay inside of the internal network behind loadbalancers, proxy, firewall etc. This is more concern for the network and admin guys about how they configure it.

Comment: @Nurzhan do you know any loadbalancer supporting jks format? Thanks

Comment: @Van, No, I don't know.